# Is Python, but not other languages, used often for scientific applications? If yes, then why Python?

Tags: python

I have seen that Python has been used in many scientific commercial applications. I use Ruby as my main language, but I do find almost no scientific application of Ruby in my neighbourhood. Is this observation valid?

If yes, then what can be the reason why Python in used much more often for scientific-applications? Is it just a culture of scientific society? Python community advertised a lot in scientific communities? Or are there reasons in the implementation of the language? To my eyes, Python is as general-purpose as Ruby or Perl. Are script languages more advantageous for scientific community because of the low-learning cost or something else? If (perceived) learning costs are small enough, functional and logic languages could have been more popular?

Comment: SO is not a place to look for opinions.

Comment: http://www.numpy.org/ and a TON of stuff built on top of it

Comment: Short answer: The epic libraries.

Comment: If you include genetics in scientific applications, then, no, python is not the king. perl has a good market share.

Comment: @justhalf aha, I did not know. I thought this question was suitable on SO because this is a sort of questions we cannot simply google, but have to consult experts. I appreciate if you can tell me where else I could post this question or can research.

Comment: @NPE, this means that many people in sci py community started with numpy or another sci package and continued to stick to them and/or extend their programming jobs with py?

Comment: @mouviciel aha, there are very common perl libs in genetics? Or what can be the reasons why they use Perl in genetics?

Comment: @taro - Take a look at: [Genetics 211: How Perl Saved the Human Genome Project](http://genetics.stanford.edu/gene211/handouts/How_Perl_HGP.html)

Comment: @NPE It seems that, in a way, the background how py got popularity in sci community is similar to the process Ruby got popularity with the introduction of Rails... Is this a good assumption?

Comment: @mouciciel I read through the article and came to 'I think several factors are responsible:'. All points can be useful for genetics researchers, but are not so specific features only with Perl. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Python has a strong position in scientific computing:
Large community of users, easy to find help and documentation.
Extensive ecosystem of scientific libraries and environments
[numpy](https://numpy.org):  - Numerical Python

The most noticeable features of python are:-

1. Great performance due to close integration with time-tested and
   highly optimized codes written in C and Fortran: blas, altas blas,
   lapack, arpack, Intel MKL.
2. Good support for Parallel processing with
   processes and threads Interprocess communication (MPI) GPU computing
   (OpenCL and CUDA).
3. Readily available and suitable for use on
   high-performance computing clusters.
4. No license costs, no
   unnecessary use of research budget.

For more info, visit [ipython](https://nbviewer.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-0-Scientific-Computing-with-Python.ipynb)

Comment: aha, Python can control both multi-processes and multi-threads?<br />With regard to the performance, it sure depends on the application, but as far as I referred to some of inter-language benchmarks http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/, Python does not significantly outperform other scripting languages overall.<br /> 4 looks like a convincing factor that py is preferred by some communities over Matlab etc.